# Have a mysql query I'd like to be able to run with order by from second table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT * 
FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable 
WHERE primaryGenreName='".$ov['title']."'
  AND composed='1' AND 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as c 
   FROM new_apps 
   WHERE trackId=dtable.trackId AND top>0) > 0 
ORDER BY top ASC
```

What I want to do here is to `ORDER BY` top of table new_apps not `app_detailsvvv` as it doesn't even have a top field, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `INNER JOIN` for this. This would be your query:

```
SELECT dtable.* FROM app_detailsvvv as dtable 
INNER JOIN new_apps ON new_apps.trackId=dtable.trackId
WHERE primaryGenreName='".$ov['title']."'
    AND composed='1' AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as c
    FROM new_apps
    WHERE trackId=dtable.trackId AND top>0) > 0
ORDER BY new_apps.top ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, how would it go with a UNION  to select from app_detailsvvv where tehre is nothing to select out of new_apps

Comment: @lbennet You mean only selecting from `dtable`? You would just do `SELECT dtable.*`... I'll fix that in my answer.